# Cop arrests nurse despite fully knowing that she had done nothing wrong. Will a personal lawsuit against the cop be likely to win?

Tags: united-states, police, arrest, false-arrest

Officer Jeff Payne put Alex Wubbels a hospital nurse under arrest even though it was ever so blatant that she had done nothing wrong. Will suing this cop personally be likely to succeed?

I've read online that it can be very difficult to sue officers personally because of investigatorial immunity. However it did also state that if the evidence clearly shows that the officer was acting unlawfully it is possible to win the suit.

In this specific case of the Utah hospital nurse being falsely arrested, is the body cam footage in conjunction with the CCTV and all the witness testimony enough to successfully file a lawsuit against this officer personally?

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to sue the officer personally; it seem like it would be easier to make a case against the city, and they have a lot more money.

Comment: @NateEldredge Because taking the money from the city is just unfair to those whom had nothing to do with this case but more importantly it relieves personal responsibility from the police officer involved.

Comment: @NateEldredge why not sue them both?

Comment: @Ryan "taking the money from the city is just unfair to those whom had nothing to do with this case..." The city is a government entity which can be held legally responsible for the actions of their employees.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch I never said that this wasn't the case. I guess Americans are more focused on getting a fat pay check from the city rather than seeing an actual bad cop put into the ground for grossly abusing his power.

Comment: @Ryan The law, like anything, can be abused. And, from your question and subsequent comments, I'm not convinced you are looking for a reasoned answer based on the law.

Comment: @Ryan: Well, I am not sure in what sense a personal lawsuit, if successful, would "put him into the ground". It would cost him some money, perhaps most of his assets, but unless he is particularly wealthy it may not even cover the plaintiff's legal fees.  Then he can declare bankruptcy and begin again.  I don't know that such a suit would have any direct effect on his ability to continue serving as a police officer; that's a decision made by the city, and a personal lawsuit against the officer doesn't put any pressure on them.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch How so? I explicitly asked if the evidence available in this specific case would be sufficient enough to win the lawsuit if it were filed. How is that not based on law?

Comment: @Ryan "...if the evidence available in this specific case would be sufficient enough to win the lawsuit..." That question _is_ based on the law in the sense that a lawsuit deals with the law; but the qualifier "If he could win" is a subjective judgement. Winning a civil lawsuit (and even a criminal suit) is subjective, no matter the evidence, even if it is video. So that's an answer to your question: winning a lawsuit is an exercise in subjective judgement by a judge and jury.

Comment: @ryan : Would you say "They had nothing to do with it" or "Them had nothing to do with it"? If "they" rather than "them" is appropriate, then so is "who" rather than "whom" .

Comment: As I understand it, the law says a police phlebotomist is permitted to take a blood sample from a hospital patient if, but only if, the patient is under arrest or the officer has a warrant or the patient consents. None of those three things happened.

Comment: @NateEldredge At least in England and Wales, if an employee is sued for something they did during the course of their work, the employee can "join" their employer to the action and the employer becomes jointly liable.  I have no idea if Utah has similar rules.